# Vector Autoregressive Models (VAR) and error terms correlation

Tags: self-study, correlation, residuals, assumptions, vector-autoregression

Before all I want to clarify, I am not looking for a direct answer in the following question but more of a clarification. I am doing a master's degree and the question is part of an assignment, so i don't want to have an answer (I want to find it alone) but I am looking whether the assignment really has an actual answer or there is something I didn't understand correctly.

Suppose we have the following autoregressive model:

$y_{1t}=β_{10}-β_{12} y_{2t}+γ_{11} y_{1t-1}+γ_{12} y_{2t-1}+u_{1t}$
$y_{2t}=β_{20}-β_{21} y_{1t}+γ_{21} y_{1t-1}+γ_{22} y_{2t-1}+u_{2t}$

While i was studying the unit, the **assumptions** where that the Y variables are stationary, that the error terms are IID(0,σ^2) and most importantly that the error terms are **uncorrelated**. All further analysis on VAR models is based on these assumptions.

In my assignment though I am asked to prove that $E(u_{1t},u_{2t})=0$, while I have the other assumptions (error terms IID and Y variables stationary) so actually to prove what in the unit (and the book) is always assumed.

I am not looking for the proof, I will try to derive it, but I want somebody to explain to me if this can be actually proved. I was under the impression, while reading the unit, that $E(u_{1t},u_{2t})=0$ is an assumption we make a priori to help us analyze the VAR models and not something that can be proved in all cases.

Let me know if there is something I am missing here, I am a bit lost.

Comment: Given your elaboration, I suppose the [tag:self-study] tag applies here.